# Initialise connections and batch service on app start

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

This query is specific to Next JS `version 13` in Beta state.

I want to kick off a batch service to run every 24hours and also connect to mongo db

when the application starts.

In the previous versions, this could have been achieved by calling relevant functions within

the app.js file. If this was a node app, I could have called em inside the main index.js file.

How would we do this in NextJS 13? At present I am calling them inside the main pages.tsx file

which would lead to localhost:3000/. It does work.

But is this correct or is there a better correct way to do this?

```
// location /src/app/page.tsx

import { checkOrInitializeDbConnection } from '@/utils/database/connection';
import { kickOff24hourlyBatchService } from '@/utils/batch/kickOff24hourlyBatchService';

const Home = () => {
  checkOrInitializeDbConnection();
  kickOff24hourlyBatchService();
  return (
    <div>
      Home
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```